# Pandas Dataframe Aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have the following dataframe (I didnt include an index here, but obvisouly there is also an index)

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 62 | 1000 |
| 62 | 55 | 1200 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now I would like to aggregate those two columns, since I do not care if the ID is in the column ID_1 or in ID_2.

I would like to get the following result:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 62 | 2200 |
| 62 | 55 | 2200 |
| ... | ... | ... |

That means that I want to sum the Count column over all the rows in my dataframe where two IDs are the same (doesnt care if they are in ID_1 column or ID_2 column).

I thought about grouping the dataframe, but that did not work properly.

I am happy for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create virtual groups:

```
make_group = lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))

df['Count'] = df.groupby(df[['ID_1', 'ID_2']].apply(make_group, axis=1))['Count'] \
                .transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID_1  ID_2  Count
0    55    62   2200
1    62    55   2200

# virtual groups
>>> df[['ID_1', 'ID_2']].apply(make_group, axis=1)
0    (55, 62)
1    (55, 62)
dtype: object
```

Comment: HINT: I agree with the approach, but this will slower for larger datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the ID columns row wise

```
df[['ID_1', 'ID_2']] = np.sort(df[['ID_1', 'ID_2']], axis=1)
```

Groupby the ID columns now

```
df.groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2']).transform(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

sort row values using np.sort , groupby and aggregate. Code below

```
df=df.assign(Count=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values), columns=df.columns).groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).transform('sum'))
```

Alternatively use agg('sort') to sort and then groupby

```
df[df.filter(regex='^ID').columns] =df.filter(regex='^ID').agg('sort')
df['Count']=df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).transform('sum')



    ID_1  ID_2  Count
0    55    62   2200
1    62    55   2200
```